# Angular router in external interceptor lib/module

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router, angular-http-interceptors, angular-library

I'm working in creating a external lib what main purpose is to implement a unique interceptor for my all web apps.

Basically I created an Angular lib and I implement that lib in my web app and it works but when I need to redirect to antoher internal route through Angular router, that is not possible.

My questions are: is there any other way to do that? or can I create a custom router and just passing the routes to the external lib in order to set the routes to the custom router?
What about inject the router dependency to the external lib interceptor? is that possible?

My Code:

App.module

```
//Routing
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

//Libs
import { AuthInterceptor } from 'auth-lib';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/layout/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ForbiddenComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    BasicComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ProfileService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

External interceptor lib

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor (private router: Router) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error => {
                    this.handleAuthError(error);
                    return of(error);
                    }) as any);
    }

    private handleAuthError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
        if (error.status === FORBIDDEN) {
            console.log('SESSION STATUS: FORDIBBEN');
            //window.location.href = ERR_AUTH_URL; //Redirect works, but this refresh the web app
            this.router.navigate([ERR_AUTH_URL]);
        }
        throw error;
    }

}
```

Comment: You want your auth lib to redirect to url specified by the app using it?

Comment: that's correct, for example in the code above, when the status is FORBIDDEN I need to redirect to ERR_AUTH_URL (variable with value = 'error') that route is mapped in the web app

Comment: all you need to do is define an injection token (or tokens) and let application provide values for that tokens like you did with APP_BASE_HREF.

Comment: I'm not a really expert in Angular, do you have any example about this?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just found the solution for this, I only modified this Line

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, deps: [Router], multi: true },
```

And it works as I expected